# Using user input variables in PandaSQL

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandasql

I'm trying to use pandaSQL on a dataframe that I have and I'm wondering if there's a way to use variables or if there's another way to do it. What I'm trying to do is setting user input as a variable and then trying to use that in the SQL statement. I want to display every instance that a shape when input. I'm trying stuff along the lines of:

```
variable1 = input("Enter shape here: ")
print pysqldf("SELECT imageNum FROM df WHERE shape1 = variable1 ")
```

but so far no luck. Everything else is working fine, I'm just running into trouble when introducing variables. Is this possible in pandaSQL and if not, what workarounds could I use?

Comment: What's wrong with just constructing the string : `"SELECT imageNum FROM df WHERE shape1 = ' + variable1`?

Comment: I may just be concatenating wrong, but I get a "None" result whenever I try something like that. When I try it your way specifically, I get: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [imageName]
Index: []

Comment: try a query that definitely works and test whether your string matches the query that generates an expected result

Comment: It works fine. It's just the implementation of variables that's messing me up

Comment: Sorry you'll have to explain better, please show what does and doesn't work and I suggest printing the query string to confirm it definitely matches what does work

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass the `WHERE` clause in the SQL query an argument in blockquotes, i.e.:

> SELECT imageNum FROM df WHERE shape1 = "square".

So you'll need to pass a string that includes the quotation marks. Try the following:

> variable1 = input("Enter shape here: ")
>
> variable1str = "\"" + variable1 +"\""
>
> print pysqldf("SELECT imageNum FROM df WHERE shape1 = variable1str ")

This way, if your input is, say, `"square"`:

> print variable1
>   `> square
>
> print variable1str
>   '> "square"