# Use of parameters to protect against user-entered search values

Tags: python, pandasql

Using `pandas` and a `sqlite3` backend, I'm able to use `param` to safely provide user-provided search values, ala:

```
In [66]: df = pd.DataFrame({"x":range(10), "y":range(10)})
# db is an existing pandas sqlite3 connection
In [67]: df.to_sql('df', rb.db)
In [68]: pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT y FROM df WHERE x = ?""", rb.db, params=(4,))
   y
0  4
```

**Q: Is there a way to do it directly on the `DataFrame` without dumping it into a sqlite backend (whether in-memory or file-backed)?**

Something akin to:

```
pandasql.sqldf("SELECT y FROM df WHERE x = ?", params=(4,), globals())
```

(which does not work, obviously). The listed arguments to `pandasql.sqldf` does not include anything obvious, so I'm guessing that I'll have to either (a) create a temporary sqlite3 in-memory cache and query against that, or (b) take the risk of SQL-injection or combat it manually. The latter would use something like:

```
pandasql.sqldf("SELECT y FROM df WHERE x = {0}".format(*[ '"' + x + '"' for x in ['4'] ]), globals())
```

Right now I'm creating the list of "where" variable dynamically, so though it's `WHERE x = ?` here, it is often multiple variables and/or multiple hits of a variable, such as `WHERE x like ? OR y like ? OR z > ?`. Creation of this string is straight-forward and creation of the list of values-for-comparison is equally "done"; it's the use of user-provided search values that is bothersome.

Not the same question as [29501895](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501895/using-user-input-variables-in-pandasql); because I'm concerned about SQL-injection, using local variables does not solve the problem.